# I'm using @UniqueConstraint in the below code.when im using saveall() method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

> I'm using @UniqueConstraint in the below code.when im using saveall()
>   method to save the data,when constraint violation fails for the first
>   data remaining values are also not saving.

```
   @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "tradeStartTime", "tradeEndTime", "contract" }))
public class TradingHours {
                @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
                private Integer id;
                private ZonedDateTime tradeStartTime;
                private ZonedDateTime tradeEndTime;
                @ManyToOne
                @JoinColumn(name = "contract")
                private Contract contract;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Can you please more specific?

Comment: im using saveall() method to save data which has 150 records.but in my first record constraint violation exception occurs because of that remaining 149 records are also not saving.i want to save remaining records without constraint violation

Comment: Okay, then my suggestion would be that you manage the exception in order to continue. So my unique idea now it is you create a base repository in order to override `saveAll(List<S> list)` and you can control from there. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to continue bulk insert after transaction fail. If you need to save all remaining values, you should save each value separately in `save()` method marked as `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`, take a look at [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html).
You also have to catch `DataIntegrityViolationException` somewhere until it breaks somthenig else.